# Merging consesqutive non-overlapping ranges after insertion

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose you have a table like this:

```
+-------+-----+------+
| start | end | size |
+-------+-----+------+
|     0 |  9  |   10 |
|    12 |  12 |    1 |
|    30 |  50 |   21 |
+-------+-----+------+
```

And you insert `(11, 11, 1)` so that now you have (Assuming index on `start` column:

```
+-------+-----+------+
| start | end | size |
+-------+-----+------+
|     0 |  9  |   10 |
|    11 |  11 |    1 |
|    12 |  12 |    1 |
|    30 |  50 |   21 |
+-------+-----+------+
```

After you insert this row, how can you efficiently merge the two consecutive ranges to end up with table like this:

```
+-------+-----+------+
| start | end | size |
+-------+-----+------+
|     0 |  9  |   10 |
|    11 |  12 |    2 |
|    30 |  50 |   21 |
+-------+-----+------+
```

EDIT:
- Apologize I messed up the tables, they should be fixed now
- I would like to modify the table in-place after insertion

Comment: Do you want to change the data in place or just retrieve the rows in this format?

Comment: Why not merge `0 - 12`?

Comment: Why did you merge `11` with `0-10` instead of `12`?

Comment: I apologize, had a brain fart regarding the merging of 0-12. The table is fixed now.


@GordonLinoff I would like to change the table in-place

Answer (score 0):

Use the Below code

```
select min("start") as "Start",max("end") as "End",sum("size") as "Size"
from "Test112" group by "size"
order by "Start"

0;10;11
11;12;2
30;50;21
```